# Trouble converting POSTGIS query to GeoDjango query

Tags: sql, django, postgis, postgresql-9.1, geodjango

I am new to POSTGIS and GeoDjango. I have a query working in POSTGIS, however, I am having difficulty converting it into a GeoDjango query.

My table `world_node` contains two columns: `node` - integer, and  `mpoint` - Geometric Point

POSTGIS SQL Query(Working):

```sql
SELECT * FROM world_node 
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-100 0, 0 150, 150 0, 0 -100, -100 0))', 4326), mpoint);
```

I am trying to get all the points that are contained within the polygon specified and it works fine.

Kindly help me with the GeoDjango syntax. Here is my code so far:

```
poly = GEOSGeometry('Polygon((-100 0, 0 150, 150 0, 0 -100, -100 0))', 4326)
nodes = Nodes.objects.filter(poly__contains=mpoint)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'mpoint' is not defined
```

Note: mpoint is a column in my Table and also a field in my Node class in models.py

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, you should switch 'poly' and 'mpoint' like this:

nodes = Nodes.objects.filter(mpoint__contains=poly)